# Android View losing data on scroll

Tags: android, view, expandablelistview

I have an application made up of an ExpandableList, whose children are data collection widgets like CheckBoxes and EditText. Once data is entered, it is immediately lost when the list is scrolled.
What may be the problem or solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found a link that explains the problem and/or solution

[EditText items in a scrolling list lose their changes when scrolled off the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036296)

> List rows get recycled. Your Cursor
>   may have 1,000 records, but there are
>   not going to be 1,000 EditText 
>   widgets created if you scroll through
>   the list. Rather, there will be 10 or
>   so, depending on how many rows are
>   simultaneously visible. Rows get
>   recycled, and the binding operation
>   will replace the old EditText value
>   with a new value from the Cursor  for
>   whatever row just scrolled onto the
>   screen, replacing whatever was there
>   before (previous value from the
>   database or a user-edited value).