# EditText loses content on scroll in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have list item with `EditText` in it, I don't know how many items there will be. I have a problem when I enter some text in `EditText`, and then scroll down a `ListView`, after I've scroll up again there is no text in my first `EditText`, or there is some text from other `EditText` from `ListView`.

I've tried `TextWatcher`, and saving data to array, but problems is that returned position of view in `ListView` isn't always right, so I lost some data from array.

Here is my code:

```
public class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public String[] Current;
    ArrayList<String> MeterName, PreviousReading, Current_Reading;
    JSONArray getArray_Meter_Reading;

    public EfficientAdapter(Context context, JSONArray getArray_Meter_Reading) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.getArray_Meter_Reading = getArray_Meter_Reading;
        MeterName = new ArrayList<String>();
        PreviousReading = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < getArray_Meter_Reading.length(); i++) {
            try {
                String Meter_Name = getArray_Meter_Reading.getJSONObject(i)
                        .getString("MeterName").toString();
                String previous_Meter_Reading = getArray_Meter_Reading
                        .getJSONObject(i).getString("PrevMeterReading")
                        .toString();
                MeterName.add(Meter_Name);
                PreviousReading.add(previous_Meter_Reading);

                // Meter[i]=MeterName.get(i);
                // Previous[i]=PreviousReading.get(i);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {

        return getArray_Meter_Reading.length();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.meter_reading_list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.adp_MeterName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_Meter_Name);
            holder.adp_Previous = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_Previous);
            holder.adp_Current = (EditText) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.ed_Current);

            holder.adp_Current.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int before, int count) {

                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int count, int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    Current[holder.ref] = s.toString();

                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.ref = position;
        holder.adp_MeterName.setText(MeterName.get(position));
        holder.adp_Previous.setText(PreviousReading.get(position));
        // holder.adp_Current.setHint(MeterName.get(position));

        // holder.adp_Current.setText(PreviousReading.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView adp_MeterName, adp_Previous;
        EditText adp_Current;
        int ref;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this:

```
public class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
public String[] Current;
ArrayList<String> MeterName, PreviousReading, Current_Reading;
JSONArray getArray_Meter_Reading;
public static HashMap<Integer,String> myList=new HashMap<Integer,String>();

public EfficientAdapter(Context context, JSONArray getArray_Meter_Reading) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.getArray_Meter_Reading = getArray_Meter_Reading;
    MeterName = new ArrayList<String>();
    PreviousReading = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < getArray_Meter_Reading.length(); i++) {
        try {
            String Meter_Name = getArray_Meter_Reading.getJSONObject(i)
                    .getString("MeterName").toString();
            String previous_Meter_Reading = getArray_Meter_Reading
                    .getJSONObject(i).getString("PrevMeterReading")
                    .toString();
            MeterName.add(Meter_Name);
            PreviousReading.add(previous_Meter_Reading);

            // Meter[i]=MeterName.get(i);
            // Previous[i]=PreviousReading.get(i);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // initialize myList
    for(int i=0;i<JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH;i++)
    {
       myList.put(i,"");
    }
}

public int getCount() {

    return getArray_Meter_Reading.length();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    final int pos=position;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.meter_reading_list, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.adp_MeterName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_Meter_Name);
        holder.adp_Previous = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_Previous);
        holder.adp_Current = (EditText) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ed_Current);


        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
     holder.adp_Current.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                Current[holder.ref] = s.toString();
                myList.put(pos,s.toString.trim());
            }
        });
    holder.ref = position;
    holder.adp_MeterName.setText(MeterName.get(position));
    holder.adp_Previous.setText(PreviousReading.get(position));
    // holder.adp_Current.setHint(MeterName.get(position));

    // holder.adp_Current.setText(PreviousReading.get(position));

    holder.adp_Current.setText(myList.get(position));

    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView adp_MeterName, adp_Previous;
    EditText adp_Current;
    int ref;

}

}
```

Here I have included a HashMap object which will keep an eye on if EditText contains value or not.And when you scroll the listview,it will be rendered again by calling its getView method along with the text associated with each edittext.

In this code,when you firstly load listview,all your edittext will be with no text.once you enter some text,it will be noted in myList.So when you again render the list,your text would be prevented.

One more thing,you should implement textwatcher outside if(convertView==null)..else.. block.That's a better practice!

Comment: have you looked into the code i suggested? it contains a HashMap object there.go through the code first!

Comment: what problem i face is when type some value in 1st edittext and i scroll down to the list,value in 1st edittext is shown is some other edittext box. can plz give solution for that im facing this problem from last three day .

Comment: Try this code out.i think,it will solve your problem.just give it a try and let me know!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7849/discussion-between-hiral-and-sachin-gurnani)

Comment: it works fine thank you very much and i will tell after testing the app thank you so much

Comment: @Hiral would you mind explaining why it's better practice to implement the textWatcher outside the if(convertView==null) block?

Answer (score 9):

I was having the exact same problem with a project I was working on. All solutions I had found also mentioned using the `textChangeListener`, however due to the nature of the list, and with an `EditText` in each row view, this was very inefficient. I took a separate approach using the `EditText.setOnFocusChangeListener()`.

I attached this to each EditText within the getView method. The reason this works so well is it is called when the user switches to a different edittext or scrolls so the current row is off the screen which causes the `EditText` to lose focus.

In the onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) within the listener I simply put:

```
if (!hasFocus) {
                EditText et = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.groupAmount);                  
                data.get(position).put("dueAmount", et.getText().toString().trim());
            }
```

In my example I am storing the entered value into my data used to populate the views on each getView call, but this should still show how to access the data the User entered. Just make sure you attempt to take this stored data and try populating the editText at the corresponding position.

Hope this helps.

**Posting my full adapter here for reference**

```
public class memberlistadapter extends BaseAdapter {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
public ArrayList<Hashtable<String, String>> data;
ViewHolder viewHolder;
public static HashMap<Integer,String> myList=new HashMap<Integer,String>();

public memberlistadapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public memberlistadapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Hashtable<String, String>> objects) {
    super();
    mInflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    //this.activity = activity;
    this.data = objects;
    Log.d("data", data.toString());
}

public void clear() {
    this.data.clear();
    viewHolder = null;
}

public void setData(ArrayList<Hashtable<String, String>> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int item) {
    return data.get(item);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.member_amount_child, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.nameText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grp_amt_child);
        viewHolder.amountText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupAmount);
        viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.memberCheckNotif);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    //Log.d("data at "+position, data.get(position).toString());
    String amt = data.get(position).get("dueAmount");
    String name = data.get(position).get("name");
    String check = data.get(position).get("reminder");

    viewHolder.nameText.setText(name);
    try {
    if (amt.length() > 0 && !amt.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
        viewHolder.amountText.setText(amt);
    } else {
        viewHolder.amountText.setText("");
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        viewHolder.amountText.setText("");
    }

    viewHolder.amountText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                EditText et = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.groupAmount);
                data.get(position).put("dueAmount", et.getText().toString().trim());
            }
        }
    });

    try {
    if (check.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
    }
    viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                data.get(position).put("reminder", "True");
            } else {
                data.get(position).put("reminder", "False");
            }
        }
    });
    if (position == 0) {
        viewHolder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.amountText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.nameText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        viewHolder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.amountText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.nameText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView nameText;
    EditText amountText;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}
}
```

Comment: this doesnt solve the problem at all. If you put some text on a Edit Text and then scroll, the first edit text doesnt lose focus and the input get lost.

Comment: @kiduxa Use `addTextChangedListener` instead of `setOnClickListener` for EditText and put  `vendorList.get(position).put("preference", et_preference.getText().toString().trim());` in **afterTextChanged**

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this or see on the right the related posts section

[EditText loses content on scroll in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772714/edittext-loses-content-on-scroll-in-listview?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

First, declare a `String[]` or `List<String>` member variable (**inside** the class **outside** the `getView()`) for storing the input text from your `EditText` object, and record the text in `addTextChangeListener()` you set on the `EditText` object.

Second, put your `setText()` after (**not inside**) the `addTextChangeListener()`.

```
    viewHolder.editText.removeTextChangedListener(viewHolder.textWatcher);

    viewHolder.textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            mInputs[position] = editable.toString();            //record input

            viewHolder.editText.setSelection(viewHolder.editText.getText().length());       //set cursor to the end
        }
    };

    viewHolder.editText.addTextChangedListener(viewHolder.textWatcher);
    viewHolder.editText.setText(mInputs[position]);
```

---

```
private class ViewHolder {
    EditText editText;
    TextWatcher textWatcher;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        editText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_editText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227)