# Spinner data is going to vanish when scrolling ListView customAdabter

Tags: android, listview, spinner

Hi I am new for android and in my ListView,I have added Spinner.

I am facing problem,when I have selected any item from spinner and,I scroll       my ListView. Spinner setSelection data is being vanished.

Please help me how can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: There are myriad of ways in which your Spinner data can vanish. How would I know which issue you are facing unless you share your code? and do refer the above link☝

Comment: When I scroll listView previous selected spinner data is reset. I want to fixed it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Spinner selection disapears when scrolling ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072456/android-spinner-selection-disapears-when-scrolling-listview)