# listview with edittext repeats the values on scroll

Tags: android, listview, scroll

This question has been asked frequently ..but nothing seems to work for me.

I have a listview with edittext .. when I scroll the listview value of edittext repeats.

Please suggest !!

code :

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

View mView = view;             //trying to reuse a recycled view

    if (mView == null) {
        //The view is not a recycled one: we have to inflate
        mView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                getResource(), parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();


        holder.row = (OEDataRow) moveLinesfinalData.get(position);

        holder.eProductName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewProductNameFinal);
        holder.eProductName.setText(holder.row.getString("name").toString());

        holder.innerLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) mView
                .findViewById(R.id.innerLinearLayout);
        holder.editTextProductId = (EditText) holder.innerLinearLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.editTextProductId);
        holder.eProductSerial = (EditText) holder.innerLinearLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.editTextSerialFinal);

        holder.BarCode = (Button) holder.innerLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.buttonBarcode);
        holder.editTextProductIdFocus = (EditText) holder.innerLinearLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.editTextProductId);

        mView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        // View recycled !
        // no need to inflate
        // no need to findViews by id
        holder = (ViewHolder) mView.getTag();
    }

    if(holder.row != null) {
        holder.editTextProductId.setText(holder.row.getInt("id").toString());

    }

    holder.eProductSerial.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String newSerial = s.toString();

            String id = holder.editTextProductIdFocus.getText().toString();
            productData.put(id,newSerial);

        }
    });

    Log.d("list", "list productData "+productData);

    holder.BarCode.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.getId();
        }
    });


    return mView;
}
```

Comment: After saving your edittext value, you have in your `getView` to check if the  current row (position) fits to the one which has the information stored. If not, put the edittext text to "".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android :EditText loses content on scroll in ListView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328301/android-edittext-loses-content-on-scroll-in-listview)

Comment: @maven : I already tried that solution not working for me ..

Answer (score 0):

You will have to save an array of Strings (something like `arrayStrings`) that contains the value of the EditText for the current position.

Set the content of `arrayStrings[position]` on your textChangedListener. Next on your getView set the queryText of your editText to whatever is on the array for the current position. Otherwise, and since the view will get recycled, expect incorrect behavior.

Comment: instead of array  i am using static LinkedHashMap<String, String> productData = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>(); .. it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if(holder.row != null) {
    holder.editTextProductId.setText(holder.row.getInt("id").toString());
}
```

Make it

```
if(holder.row != null) {
      holder.editTextProductId.setText(((OEDataRow) moveLinesfinalData.get(position)).getInt("id"));
}
```

In HolderView keep only Views IDs, not some data itself.

Comment: it says NoresourceFound

Answer (score 0):

remove:

```
 holder.row = (OEDataRow) moveLinesfinalData.get(position);
```

and change

```
if(holder.row != null) {
        holder.editTextProductId.setText(holder.row.getInt("id").toString());   
}
```

to

```
if((OEDataRow) moveLinesfinalData.get(position) != null) {
        holder.editTextProductId.setText(String.valueOf((OEDataRow) moveLinesfinalData.get(position)).getInt("id"))); 
}
```