# Keep values of editText boxes into an expandable list view on Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I created an expandable view that contains an editText box under each group.

```
    public class ExpandableActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
        ExpandableListView expListView;
        List<String> listDataHeader;
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_expandable);

            expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
            expListView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);

            // preparing list data
//custom function that populates listDataHeader and listDataChild
            prepareListData(); 

            listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
            expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Adapter Code:

```
    public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private List<String> listDataHeader;
        private HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

        public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                     HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
            this.context = context;
            this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
            this.listDataChild = listChildData;
        }


        @Override
        public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.e_list_item, null);
            }

            TextView vw_text_sub = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.esubt);
            EditText vw_edit = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eedit);

            vw_text_sub.setText(childText);

            vw_edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {            
                        //store value?
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }



        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.e_list_group, null);
            }

            TextView vw_header = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eheader);
            vw_header.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            vw_header.setText(headerTitle);

            return convertView;
        }

// other overridden methods here....

    }
```

Because of the adapter functionality that is to recycle the views, whenever i type some text in an edit box this value is either lost or copied in other edit boxes too when i am scrolling up and down.

In list view an array is used to store values of edit boxes.

What is the best way to do it in an expandable list view? Array of arrays?
Can you provide an example for an expandable list view and not a list view?

EDIT: Tried this but i also have problems:

```
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.e_list_item, null);
        }

        TextView vw_text_sub = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.esubt);
        EditText vw_edit = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eedit);

        vw_text_sub.setText(childText);
        if(tmp[groupPosition][childPosition] != null) {
            vw_edit.setText(tmp[groupPosition][childPosition]);
        }else{
            vw_edit.setText("");
        }

        vw_edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                tmp[groupPosition][childPosition] = arg0.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

tmp is an array String[10][10]. My groups are 3 and children are max 7 in a group, so the array is not smaller than my data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android :EditText loses content on scroll in ListView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328301/android-edittext-loses-content-on-scroll-in-listview)

Comment: this is for list view. I have an expandable list view.

Comment: It's not mater @mike_x_, you need to use `addTextChangedListener` to store value before scrolling, as you don't persist the value your data not be saved and you lost that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the TestWatcher. It fires each method a lot of times and i have not found out why. So the solution was to use FocusChangeListener or much better to show an alertDialog in order to fill the field. Then on positive button click i stored the data in the array.

So by replacing TextWatcher i managed to solve the problem.