# Can not write into EditText of Listview in Android

Tags: android

I have one EditText into listview, i m hidding/showing editText by clicking on particular row.
when editText show and i m trying to write into editText i am not able to write into particular editText. please help me.Thanks

Comment: Please upload the code with question.

Comment: may answer in stack-overflow for this problem . please search it.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015853/android-how-to-make-edittext-editable-inside-a-listview

Comment: @shripal as Vigbyor said, we are helpless. Please provide your source code by editing your question.

Comment: You can focus on EditText after showing it in ListView

Answer (score 0):

This is may be related to [EditText in ListView Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385890/android-edittext-in-listview-issue)

or

[EditText items in a scrolling list lose their changes when scrolled off the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036296/edittext-items-in-a-scrolling-list-lose-their-changes-when-scrolled-off-the-scre)

or

[EditText loses content on scroll in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772714/edittext-loses-content-on-scroll-in-listview?rq=1)

EDIT: In addition you can play with this example [Android Focusable EditText inside ListView](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/)